# How to specify font preferences in XeTeX math mode?

Tags: fonts, xetex

I would like to use specific fonts in the math formulas in a document I am writing. I mainly want to use the "great escape" font. After some search on the web I tried the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
\setmainfont{The Great Escape}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin){The Great Escape}
\begin{document}
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, since this font does not have all characters, the compiler says that something was replaced with some default. What I would like to do is to specify what to use if a symbol is not available. In math mode (instead of the default), in order of preference I would like to use

1. The Great Escape
2. NoteWorthy
3. TeX Gyre Pagella

I have The Great Escape and NoteWorthy in ttf and the TeX Gyre Pagella in otf format. Can someone suggest some solution? Instead of TeX Gyre Pagella, Cambria Math would also be an alternative.
Thanks in advance